# CSS selector for div id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a list of all the names of id which has the same class name `test-class`

```
<div class="test-container">
    <div class="test-class" id="test-1">
        //some markup
    </div>
    <div class="test-class" id="test-2">
        //some markup
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get a list of `test-1`,`test-2` when I know they have the same class name?

I tried this but it didn't work

```
var array = jQuery.makeArray($(".test-class").attr("id"));
console.log(array[0]); //test-1
console.log(array[1]); //undefined
```

It seems like .attr only returns the first id and wouldn't capture the remaining ids.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `$.map` function for that :

```
var arr = $.map($(".test-class"), function(el, i) {return el.id});

console.log(arr[0]); //test-1
console.log(arr[1]); //test-2
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVb8k/)

as a sidenote, this would'nt be hard to do without jQuery either :

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('test-class'),
    arr   = [];

for (i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    arr.push(elems[i].id);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVb8k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over using `$.each`

```
var ids = []

$.each($('div.test-class'), function(idx, el) {
    ids.push(el.id)
});
```